# Proving a recursive sequence is bounded

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm proving that the limit of the following recursive sequence is $\dfrac{10}{9}$:
$$s_0=1,\,s_n=s_{n-1}+\frac{1}{10^n}\quad\text{for }n\ge1$$
Showing that the sequence is monotonic was easy enough, but I admit I'm having more troubled with the boundedness.

I know I want to show $s_k\le\dfrac{10}{9}$ for all $k$, but I'm not sure if this is a proof by induction, or if I can use some simpler reasoning?

What I've tried:
$$\begin{align*}s_0=1&<\frac{10}{9}&\text{base case}\\\\
s_k&<\frac{10}{9}&\text{assumption}\\\\
s_{k+1}&=s_k+\frac{1}{10^k}\\
&<\frac{10}{9}+\frac{1}{10^k}\end{align*}$$
Somehow I need to show that $s_{k+1}<\dfrac{10}{9}$, but I feel like this isn't right.

**Edit** Let's say I'm writing a lesson plan for someone that hasn't learned about series yet. Is there no way to prove boundedness without introducing the concept of a series and writing the sequence as a geometric sum? The hints are great, just a bit beyond my scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a geometric series.

Since
$$(1+x+x^2+\cdot+x^n)(1-x)=1-x^{n+1}$$

then
$$s_n=\frac{1-\frac{1}{10^{n+1}}}{1-\frac1{10}}$$

and $\lim s_n=\frac{10}9$.

Also, this is
$$1.1111\ldots11$$
which is the ninth part of
$$9.999\ldots99<10$$

Comment: Another formula for $s_n$ would be $$\frac{10}9\left(1-\frac1{10^{n+1}}\right).$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Call $S=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{10^k}$

Answer (score 1):

**hint**: $s_n-s_{n-1} = \dfrac{1}{10^n}, s_{n-1}-s_{n-2} = \dfrac{1}{10^{n-1}}, s_{n-2}-s_{n-3} = \dfrac{1}{10^{n-2}},...$, and :
$s_n = (s_n-s_{n-1})+(s_{n-1}-s_{n-2})+\cdots + (s_2-s_1)+(s_1-s_0)+s_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, try to find an explicit formula for the terms $s_n$. Prove that the formula holds by induction, then proceed from there.

To get an idea of an explicit formula, calculate the first several terms, and look for a pattern.

**Added**: As an alternative, try proving that $$\frac{10}9-s_n=\frac1{10^{n+1}\cdot 9}$$ for all $n$, using induction and the recursive definition. From there, *everything* (monotonicity, boundedness, and convergence) is straightforward.